# Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set Working between Access and Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, runtime-error

I am working with both MS Access and Excel where I am sending data from Access to multiple worksheets in a single Excel workbook and formatting each of the worksheets as each is created. My issue is that the first time I run the procedure, everything works fine.

If I run the process a second time without closing and restarting (or running the Compact and Repair Database process), I am receiving the subject/title line error message when the code reaches the line `ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to preventing this error from occurring?

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow! Can you write the procedure in question?

Comment: Check which is the ActiveWindow after the process has ended.

Comment: Never use `ActiveWindow` by itself when working from outside Excel. Always reference it: `myExcelAppObject.ActiveWindow`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue.